# How to automatically create README.md markdown of directory tree listing

Tags: sed, tree, directory, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to create markdown with a directory tree listing automatically, in order to be shown in online repos like GitHub in every directory.

So, given that I'm going to use the [Linux `tree` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) that can be installed on MacOS X using `brew install tree` (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/359723/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-the-ubuntu-tree-command) for details), I came out with this solution:

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md > README.md;sed -i '' '1s/^/```/' README.md;echo \ >> README.md; sed -i '' -e '$s/$/```/' README.md
````

where the first ```` sed -i '' '1s/^/```/' README.md ```` is prepending the ```` ``` ```` chars – see [Mastering (Github) Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) for details about supported markdown.

The echo `echo \ >> README.md;` is adding a newline. Note here that I'm not using the `sed` equivalent `sed -i '' -e '$a\' filename` since this only adds a newline when it does not exists due to the `$a` pattern (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file)).

While the last ```` sed -i '' -e '$s/$/```/' README.md ```` is adding a trailing ```` ``` ```` to the file.

The `tree` command `tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md` is going to exclude some patterns, put directory first, ignore reporting file and dir count.

The result is going to be something like the following:

````
```.
├── bin
│   ├── Debug
│   │   ├── SampleLibrary.jar
│   │   ├── cooper.jar
│   │   ├── sugar.data.jar
│   │   ├── sugar.jar
│   │   └── swift.jar
│   └── Release
│       ├── SampleLibrary.jar
│       ├── cooper.jar
│       ├── sugar.data.jar
│       ├── sugar.jar
│       └── swift.jar
├── obj
│   ├── Debug
│   │   └── Android
│   │       ├── ClassLibrary2.elements.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt
│   │       └── samplelibrary.jar
│   └── Release
│       └── Android
│           ├── ClassLibrary2.elements.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt
│           └── samplelibrary.jar
├── ClassLibrary2.elements
└── ClassLibrary2.elements.user
 ```
````

You can see this markdown README.md [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/swift-promise-example/tree/master/StaticLibrary/ClassLibrary2).

This solution is not so efficient and it is limited to `-I` pattern options of `tree` to filter out unwanted dirs (let's say build directories) or file names, etc. Also it does not work properly to update an existing `README.md` markdown.

The solution should work on MacOS X (where sed has some differences to that on Linux).

Comment: Why bother post-processing to get the bracketing `\`\`\`` markers? Why not just echo them before and after? `{ echo '\`\`\`'; tree ...; echo '\`\`\`'; } > README.md`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to get source code markup is to indent everything by four spaces:

```
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md | sed 's/^/    /' > README.md
```

To do it your way, adding a new first and last line with ```` ``` ```` on each, we can do

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md |
sed '1s/^/```'$'\n''/;$s/$/'$'\n''```/' > README.md
````

where inserting a newline in the replacement string is done with a C-style escape. Alternatively, we can use `"$(printf '\n')"`:

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md |
sed '1s/^/```'"$(printf '\n')"'/;$s/$/'"$(printf '\n')"'```/' > README.md
````

These should both work with the sed on macOS.

With GNU sed, it would be a little simpler:

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md |
sed '1s/^/```\n/;$s/$/\n```/' > README.md
````

Comment: right using tabs with 4 spaces it's an alternative solution, at least working on Github markup. On `MacOS X` we should use `-i ''` to make it working.

Comment: @loretoparisi I don't think the `-i ''` is required, as we're not working in-place. `README.md` is truncated due to the redirection, and sed just reads input from a pipe and writes to the previously truncated file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this python module](https://github.com/mpascucci/treesource-doc) (I am the author).

It generats descriptive directory trees dynamically, and it has a markdown export format like the following:

`.`
`├──` **`example_folder\`**
`│   ├──` **`first_subfolder\`** *a documented folder*
`│   │   ├──` **`sub-sub1\`**
`│   │   │   └── file3.sh` *this is file 3*
`│   │   ├──` **`sub-sub2\`**
`│   │   │   └── file4.cpp` *this is file 4*
`│   │   └── random_file.rdm` *a documented file*
`│   ├──` **`second_subfolder\`** _a documented folder
`│   ├── a_text_file.txt` *a text file*
`│   ├── my_javascript.js` *this is file 1*
`│   └── test.py` *a python script*
`└── README.md` *The main readme*\

and an ASCII one of course

```
.
├── example_folder\
│   ├── first_subfolder\ (a documented folder)
│   │   ├── sub-sub1\
│   │   │   └── file3.sh (this is file 3)
│   │   ├── sub-sub2\
│   │   │   └── file4.cpp (this is file 4)
│   │   └── random_file.rdm (a documented file)
│   ├── second_subfolder\ (a documented folder with no documented files)
│   ├── a_text_file.txt (a text file)
│   ├── my_javascript.js (this is file 1)
│   └── test.py (a python script)
└── README.md (The main readme)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your markdown in VSCode and add [Ascii Tree Generator extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aprilandjan.ascii-tree-generator) from Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

1. **`Avoid Overwriting README.md Directly:`**

Instead of overwriting the README.md file directly, consider creating a temporary file, and then move it to README.md once the changes are complete. This helps prevent potential data loss if something goes wrong during the process.

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md > temp_tree.md
echo '```' >> temp_tree.md
mv temp_tree.md README.md
````

2. **Handling Code Blocks in Markdown:**

If you want to include the directory tree within a code block in Markdown, you should wrap the tree output with triple backticks (```) before and after the tree structure. The commands you provided for adding triple backticks around the tree structure are correct.

3. **Updating an Existing README.md:**

If you're updating an existing README.md file, consider preserving other content already present in the file. You can use a combination of commands to insert the generated tree structure into the existing file without overwriting it entirely.

````
tree --dirsfirst --noreport -I README.md > temp_tree.md
echo '```' >> temp_tree.md
awk '/```/{flag=!flag}flag' README.md > temp_existing_content.md
cat temp_tree.md temp_existing_content.md > README.md
````

This set of commands extracts the existing content between triple backticks and then concatenates the new tree structure with the extracted content.

Note: The awk command here looks for lines containing triple backticks and toggles a flag, allowing you to extract the content between them.